# Android app release on Play Store can't make API call

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have published an Android app on Google Play Store, but this app cannot make any API call. I have had this problem before, but adding internet permission fixed it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

However, this doesn't seem to work anymore. I am clueless. I have developed the app with Ionic (iOS version works), and I generate and sign the app bundle locally on my laptop through Android Studio. When I generate a signed APK and install this one directly on my phone, the internet works and I can make API calls. But when generating an AAB file and upload this on Google Play Store to update my app, the app's internet connection doesn't work/I can't make any API call.

I have followed many steps and description on the internet, but nothing helped. Below is my `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="0.0.6" package="app.MYAPP" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="false">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.cordova.plugin.camera.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to debug this in more detail for us to help.  How did it fail?  Did it not find the server?  Did it return a 500 error?  Did it crash when you tried to make the API call?  You need to give us more than "it didn't work".

Comment: @GabeSechan As you can read it in my answer, I have generated a signed release APK, and it works. I have debugged it & it works. It works in all other situations, except when I generate the AAB file, upload it on Play store, and download&install the app on my phone. I have had this before, and adding the permission helped. But for now, anything I did, didn't solve this issue. It looks like it crashes when I try to make the API call. Hence the "it didn't work". If I had debug info, I would have provided it with all my heart.

Comment: DOwnload it on your own device and capture the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, I am on it.

Comment: @GabeSechan Can't see anything in Logcat. My API call doesn't return anything, endlessly waiting for a response. I have set a timeout after 15 seconds. But nothing to see in my Logcat. This happens after I sign my app and install it. If I use an unsigned version or debug version, it works fine. It works fine on iPhone too..